# json_encode is extremely slow, what could I do to make it faster?

Tags: php, mysql, json, performance, processing-efficiency

I used json_encode for more than one associative tables and fields so it will make more than 600.000records to store, but the loading needs more than 11second to done, and in my case I need it to be just 1second. What should I do?
I inserted this variable to javascript in my html file.
`var a  = <?php echo json_encode(qry_x());?>;`
the qry_x is a function that provide mysql query to select all the tables that I need. But when I limit the record to 30records, it just need 1second to load, but when I don't give it limit, it need 11seconds and more to load. The size of the table I want to show is just 2MB.
This is the query:
`SELECT a.kd_food, a.nm_food, a.type, a.kd_each, c.nm_pereach, a.garnice, b.type1, b.type2, b.type3, b.type4, b.type5, b.type6, a.typeavg, a.price1, a.price2, a.price3, a.price4, a.price5, a.price6, a.price7 FROM foods AS a LEFT JOIN b AS place ON (a.kd_food=b.kd_food AND b.kd_place=001) LEFT JOIN pereach AS c ON a.kd_each=c.kd_each ORDER BY a.nm_food;`

Comment: Try to describe your problem.

Comment: your question is unclear. try to clear it with some example code and states where you are facing problem.

Comment: well, 600'000 records are not quite few. maybe you just have to accept that. maybe there *is* something that can be done with your code, but since you didn't provide any, we can not take a look, so the only currently apparent solution is to buy a server that's 11 times faster.

Comment: Be sure the issue is only in `json_encode` and not in your `qry_x` function. It's usual to find out that database queries are the bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry for not give the detail, I'm new in this thing.

Comment: Please show us the `SELECT`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: You want to display all 600K lines on a web page?  Get real!

Comment: `SELECT a.kd_food, a.nm_food, a.type, a.kd_each, c.nm_pereach, a.garnice, b.type1, b.type2, b.type3, b.type4, b.type5, b.type6, a.typeavg, a.price1, a.price2, a.price3, a.price4, a.price5, a.price6, a.price7 FROM foods AS a LEFT JOIN b AS place ON (a.kd_food=b.kd_food AND b.kd_place=001) LEFT JOIN pereach AS c ON a.kd_each=c.kd_each ORDER BY a.nm_food;`